# Common property file for multiple SQL Server Jobs

Tags: ssis, sql-server-job

In our project, we have a lot of SQL Server Jobs (Local SSIS package) and in all of them, we have some common properties.

We don't find a way to "place" these properties somewhere to be used by all the SQL Server Jobs.

For now, we used to set up these properties for each job in the "Set Values" of a step of the job but it's a little bit redundant and we think we can do better.

The question is : How/where I can put these properties to a common place to be used by all the SQL Server Jobs ?

Environment : SQL Server 2019

Comment: What's the question? Please, provide an example of job and tell us what do you want to improve

Comment: Create one config file and execute more packages with that one config file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Variables should already exist in the package to use config file but I don't find another way so I will use this way.